# Algorithms in Invariant Theory

Tags: computer-algebra, computational-geometry, geometric-invariant-theory, algorithms, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be a polynomial representation of the general linear group $\Gamma:=\DeclareMathOperator{\Gl}{Gl}\Gl_n(\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb C}\C)$.

In chapter 4.6 of his book "*Algorithms in Invariant Theory*", [Bernd Sturmfels](http://math.berkeley.edu/~bernd/index.html) describes an algorithm he calls *Hilbert's Algorithm*, which calculates a finite set of generators for the ring of invariants 
$$\C[V]^\Gamma = \left\{~ f\in\C[V] ~:~ \forall\gamma\in\Gamma:~ \gamma.f=f ~\right\}.$$
My question: Are there any software implementations of this algorithm (or, of any algorithm that does the same thing) in computer algebra systems? I would prefer free software,  but if the only implementation is in a commercial product, I'd still use it.

Comment: I have no useful comment on this very interesting question (although I think I heard people talking about implementing this recently at a Macaulay2 conference -- but it's not there yet), but I thought it might be worth remarking that this appears to me to be the 5000th question in ag.algebraic-geometry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/) (not free, unfortunately) is capable of this. The method [`FundamentalInvariants(R) : RngInvar -> RngMPol`](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/1197#12744) should do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.0622

Answer (score 1):

I dont know whether this helps : http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S074771711200079X