What is the state of invariant theory?
I have often heard that Hilbert killed invariant theory, but I see that there computational invariant theory seems to be an active field, and I understand that geometric invariant theory arose from algebraic invariant theory.
What else is going on with algebraic invariant theory?
Are there contemporary surveys on open problems and the current focus of algebraic invariant theory? Is most research in the computational aspects?

There is a recent book by De Concini and Procesi with some fairly recent results in it. Usually the question is to find generators and relations for the invariant rings of a family of groups acting on a family of spaces (e.g., $\operatorname{GL}_n$ acting on $K^{n\times n}$ by conjugation). This is not a computational problem, since the families are typically infinite (all $n$, not just a few). Also, fields of positive characteristic offer a challenge in many situation where the characteristic-$0$ theory can be derived from general facts.

Also I expect a lot of activity to follow in the anticommutative and noncommutative settings (which lag behind the commutative one for historical reasons).

For an example of open problem, see my article mentioned at the end of my MO answer https://mathoverflow.net/questions/286872/what-is-currently-feasible-in-invariant-theory-for-binary-forms/286892#286892

A fairly recent survey article appeared in https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.12709

The work of Andrew Snowden and his collaborators is worth looking at. See for example "The ideal of relations for the ring of invariants of $n$ points on the line" and other work in a similar vein.
